# Find the surface area of that part of the cylinder

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, surface-integrals, multiple-integral, stokes-theorem

Find the surface area of that part of the cylinder given by $\mathbf{r}(u,v) = 3\cos u \mathbf{i} + 3\sin u\mathbf{j} + v\mathbf{k}$ over the region where $0\leq u \leq2\pi$ and $0\leq v \leq2$.

The answer is $12\pi$.

I am trying to solve this but I am not understanding how to do this. I am thinking about either Stoke's theorem or the Divergence theorem. In both cases, we have to take the derivative with respect to x and y and z, but it is in terms with u and v.

Also, how would you find the normal vector for Stoke's theorem? Or is it better to just use the Divergence Theorem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear why you would use Stoke's theorem or divergence,
although sometimes people set relatively trivial exercises like this
in order to give you a way to check your application of the theorem.
(But in that case I'd expect there to have been more guidance on how to
set up the problem; for example, "Use this vector field ... .")

The quantities $u$ and $v$ are just parameters that you can vary within
the given intervals; for each possible pair of values $(u,v)$ you can plug
those values into the formula 
$3\cos u \mathbf{i} + 3\sin u\mathbf{j} + v\mathbf{k}$
and the result will be a point on the desired surface.

Try drawing a picture of the surface.
You can start by drawing just the points for which $v = 0$
(these all have the form $3\cos u \mathbf{i} + 3\sin u\mathbf{j}$,
so they lie in the $x,y$ plane).
Every other point is obtained by adding $v\mathbf{k}$ for some $v$ in $(0,2]$
to one of the $x,y$ points, so those points are all directly above
the first set of points,
that is, take your graph in the $x,y$ plane and build a wall of
height $2$ on it.

It's a very simple surface (hint: you already know it's part of a cylinder)
and you should be able to find its area easily using high-school geometry.

Comment: Is the surface a cylinder with radius 3 and height 2?

Comment: That's what I get.

Comment: However, the surface area is 30pi, isn't it? The answer is 12pi. Why is that the case?

Comment: Ah, it depends on your definition of "cylinder". This one is just the curved-wall part; it has no circular surfaces at the ends. (Notice how you can't use $u$ and $v$ to get to any points closer than $3$ units to the $z$ axis.)

Comment: Oh, so it is an open cylinder! Ok thanks!